# How can I make an app that connect to a webserver to iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-applications, webserver

I need make an app to iPhone that connect to a webserver.
This app connnect a webserver and return the content formated to iphone.

Thanks for help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestion for getting data from a web server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096299/suggestion-for-getting-data-from-a-web-server)

Comment: Hi, I learn how to do this in http://forum.iphonedevpt.com